# Changing resolution in pdf-tools PDFView

Tags: pdf

See [this solution](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13724/make-doc-view-use-mupdf-for-pdf-files) for changing the resolution in DocView.

I don't see anything like this for pdf-tools. How can I increase the resolution like `doc-view-resolution` variable would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change resolution in pdf-tools. As far as I know in poppler all PDF objects are vector-based, i.e. can be, and are, rendered arbitrary large.

Comment: More at https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools/issues/51